# jQuery dynamically update drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have jQuery fill the drop downs in my form, the data is coming from JSON.

The problem I'm having is that I can't work out how to fill the 3rd drop down box with the relevant data.

For example if you select 'California' and then 'West Coast' then I would like it to display the 'product' in the 3rd drop down which would be 'Sunshine'.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJ69R/)

I've tried to replicate my current jQuery code to access 'product.states.type' but having no luck.

```
products.states[i].type
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$('#type').on('change', function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < products.states.length; i++)
    {           
      if(products.states[i].id == $('#state').val())
      {
        for(var j = 0; j < products.states[i].type.length; j++)
        {
            if(products.states[i].type[j].id == $(this).val()){
                $('#product').html('<option></option>');
                $.each(products.states[i].type[j].product, function (index, value) {
                        $("#product").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
                });
            }

        }
      }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hJ69R/5/